# Slow gui when using webview in android

Tags: android, jquery, html, webview

Gui is slow when using  number elements in the html increases mainly when scrolling the page in the webview.
We are using android version  4.3.
jQuery for scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

Also be sure to use HW acceleration:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

in the application or activity tag in the Android manifest file